# How to create and copy jenkins jobs using shell commands.Also how to run only a few test cases out of all mentioned in the job

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, test-suite

How to **create** and **copy** jenkins jobs using **shell** commands.Also how to run only a few **test** cases out of all mentioned in the job or a suite.
What are the settings i need to change to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried the jenkins-cli but i want to use it on linux as well.so i want it through shell script.plus i think this might work for running an emulator-: ps aux | grep -ie emulator | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9..Creating and copying is something i am not able to achieve

Comment: could you please tell us how u r triggering your test cases.. there are lot of ways to trigger.. using maven-testNG is an example..

Comment: i am providing a build.xml of the test project to run the tests.I dont knw how to use maven-testng in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Copy Jenkins job ? can do so while creating a job by selecting 'copy from option'

logic of the script to run the tests has to be updated to pick selected tests to run from the suite. Jenkins has no options to select the test cases from a suite internally.

Comment: I can do so using jenkins-cli now.But the now the problem is to run only a few test cases out of the bunch and creating another job for selected ones seems like the only option.